# Simple events backbone.js error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

In running this on index.html, I get the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :", referring to

```
events: {
            "click #add-friend": "showPrompt",
        },
```

It specifically refers to the ":" here "click #add-friend": "showPrompt"
More context below. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
(function ($) {

    Friend = Backbone.Model.extend({
        // create a model to to hold friend attribute
        name: null
    });

    Friends = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        // this is our friends collection and holds out Friend models
        initialize: function(models, options) {
            this.bind("add", options.view.addFriendLi);
            // listens for "add" and calls a view function if so
        }
    });

    AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("body"),
        initialize: function () {
            this.friends = new Friends(null, {view: this});
        // creates a new friends collection when the view is initialized
        // pass it a reference to the view to create a connection between the two
        events: {
            "click #add-friend": "showPrompt"
        },
        showPrompt: function () {
            var friend_name = prompt("Who is your friend?");
            var friend_model = new Friend({name:friend_name});
            // adds a new friend model to out Friend collection
            this.friends.add(friend_model);
        },
        addFriendLi: function (model) {
            // the parameter passed is a reference to the model that was added
            $("#friends_list").append("<li>" + model.get('name') + "</li>");
        }
    });
    var appview = new AppView;
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an extra comma at the end:

```
"click #add-friend": "showPrompt" // remove the comma
```

You are also missing a closing `}` at the end of the initialize method:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.friends = new Friends(null, {view: this});
}, // add a "}," here

events: {
   "click #add-friend": "showPrompt"
},
```

Comment: Removing the comma did not help.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the "}" for your "initialize" function. Without that, it thinks that the token "events" is starting a new statement. It's all good up until the colon after the string constant, which is syntactically incorrect in that context.

Oh, and you'll also need a comma there too, to separate the value of the "initialize" property from the "events" property.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma after the property value:

```
events: {
     "click #add-friend": "showPrompt" // <-- comma removed!
},
```